# Python Kivy: How to pass an instance variable to another window (class)?

Tags: python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

I want the user to enter his email ID in the first screen (class ConnectPage), and then I want to pass that value to the other screen (the class InfoPage). I tried passing it in the build function, but it returns nothing. How should I do it?

```
class ConnectPage(FloatLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        # syntax change for super in python 2x
        super(ConnectPage, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        
        self.enter_email_id = Label(text="Email:")
        self.add_widget(self.enter_email_id)
        self.email_entered = TextInput(multiline=False)
        self.add_widget(self.email_entered)
         
        self.login_acc = Button(text="Login")
        self.add_widget(self.login_acc)
        self.login_acc.bind(on_press=self.login_btn)

    def login_btn(self, _):
        chat_app.sm.current = "Info"

    

class InfoPage(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self, email, **kwargs):
    super(InfoPage, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    self.cols = 1
    
    self.email = email
    print(self.email)

    
class ChatApp(App):

    def build(self):
        self.sm = ScreenManager()

        self.connect_page = ConnectPage()
        screen = Screen(name="Connect")
        screen.add_widget(self.connect_page)
        self.sm.add_widget(screen)

        self.info_page = InfoPage(email=chat_app.connect_page.email_entered.text)
        screen = Screen(name="Info")
        screen.add_widget(self.info_page)
        self.sm.add_widget(screen)
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `build()` method, the line:

```
self.info_page = InfoPage(email=chat_app.connect_page.email_entered.text)
```

is executed when the `ChatApp` is first built. That is long before anyone has a chance to enter their email in the `ConnectPage`, so the `email` passed to `InfoPage` at that point is `''`.

So, one way to pass the `email` to `InfoPage` is to wait until it is set in the `ConnectPage`, and that would logically be done when the user clicks on the `Login` `Button`. Here are a few changes to your code that will do that:

Change the `login_btn()` method to set an `email` property of `InfoPage`:

```
def login_btn(self, _):
    chat_app.info_page.email = self.email_entered.text
    chat_app.sm.current = "Info"
```

And  modify `InfoPage` to have such a property:

```
class InfoPage(GridLayout):
    email = StringProperty('')
```

Then you can use that `email` property in the `InfoPage`, for example:

```
Builder.load_string('''
<InfoPage>:
    cols: 1
    Label:
        text: root.email
''')
```